# jquery animation library identification

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Can anyone guide me what jquery library is used i this website, http://www.bluemountains.edu.au/, and if it is available for download or available to be bought online? I am talking about the effects on Student Life, Program and Careers menus on the main banner.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read more at http://jQuery.com. It is free to download.

Some samples

- http://buildinternet.com/live/smoothmenu/animated-menu.html ([Download](http://buildinternet.com/live/smoothmenu/animated-menu.zip))
- http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/vimeo_navigation/ ([Download](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/file.axd?file=2009/1/vimeo_navigation.zip))
- http://apycom.com/menus/16-indian-red.html ([Download](http://apycom.com/menus/16-indian-red.zip))

Hope this helps you.

Comment: this is not what op are asking

Answer (score 0):

It is here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the main banner accordion effect when you mouse over the different titles, it seems to be custom made by the author.

You can scan through the source and find the code they used, but it might no be what you are looking for here. You should probably have someone with some jQuery experience to program you one that suits your project, it’s a fairly easy task to do from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

The skew is made by the css3 and html 5 and the animation using jquery (in ie7 there no skew effect) :

```
#homepage_accordion a {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    -moz-transform: skew(-2deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-2deg, 0deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-2deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-2deg, 0deg);
    transform: skew(-2deg, 0deg);
}
```

and the script is

```
    // Let's grab all of the actors in this feature
    var $FL = jQuery('#homepage_accordion a.left');
    $FL.data({
      'wrap': $FL.find('.wrap'),
      'excerpt': $FL.find('.excerpt')
    });

    var $FM = jQuery('#homepage_accordion a.middle');
    $FM.data({
      'wrap': $FM.find('.wrap'),
      'excerpt': $FM.find('.excerpt')
    });

    var $FR = jQuery('#homepage_accordion a.right');
    $FR.data({
      'wrap': $FR.find('.wrap'),
      'excerpt': $FR.find('.excerpt')
    });


    // Set some animation options
    var animOpts = {
      duration: 600,
      queue: false,
      easing: 'easeInOutQuart'
    };


  // Now we'll add the events for each
    $FL.bind('mouseenter', function(Event) {
        $FL.data('wrap').animate({
            marginTop: 350,
            height: 150
        }, animOpts);

        $FL.data('excerpt').animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, animOpts);

        $FM.animate({
            marginLeft: 0
        }, animOpts);

        $FM.data('wrap').animate({
            marginTop: 0,
            height: 500,
            width: 300
        }, animOpts);

        $FM.data('excerpt').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, animOpts);

        $FR.data('wrap').animate({
            marginTop: 0,
            height: 500,
            width: 2000
        }, animOpts);

        $FR.data('excerpt').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, animOpts);
    });

    $FM.bind('mouseenter', function(Event) {
        $FM.data('wrap').animate({
            marginTop: 350,
            height: 150,
            width: 600
        }, animOpts);

        $FM.animate({
            marginLeft: -250
        }, animOpts);

        $FM.data('excerpt').animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, animOpts);

        $FL.data('wrap').animate({
            marginTop: 0,
            height: 500,
            width: 2000
        }, animOpts);

        $FL.data('excerpt').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, animOpts);

        $FR.data('wrap').animate({
            marginTop: 0,
            height: 500,
            width: 2000
        }, animOpts);

        $FR.data('excerpt').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, animOpts);
    });

    $FR.bind('mouseenter', function(Event) {
        $FR.data('wrap').animate({
            marginTop: 350,
            height: 150
        }, animOpts);

        $FR.data('excerpt').animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, animOpts);

        $FM.animate({
            marginLeft: -250
        }, animOpts);

        $FM.data('wrap').animate({
            marginTop: 0,
            height: 500,
            width: 300
        }, animOpts);

        $FM.data('excerpt').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, animOpts);

        $FL.data('wrap').animate({
            marginTop: 0,
            height: 500,
            width: 2000
        }, animOpts);

        $FL.data('excerpt').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, animOpts);
    });
```